# How can i get to the BIOS log file on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, memory, bios

I've recently learned that the actual memory run speed isnt necessarily
what it says on the memory cards. The actual speed is 'negotiated' based on
factors like bus speed, or clock speed, motherboard architecture and so on.
So your 800Mhz RAM  might be running at 667Mhz, or 400Mhz.

This 'negotiation' occurs at boot time. 
I'd like to see if any mention of this negotiation
is presented in the bios log file. 
Question is: How do i get to it on  Ubuntu?

Thanks to who ever replies.

Sven

Answer (score 0):

BIOS is what runs on your motherboard.  You likely can't get to it within Ubuntu unless your motherboard manufacture made a module for it (highly unlikely).  You'll have to get to it during post when the machine starts.  Usually F2 or F1, but it will say specifically what to press when you first turn on the machine.